# Adequate database structure for mixed data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, nosql

I have to create a database for sensor measurements. I have scalar data like date, serial number, firmware version, etc., but I also have array data, basically sensor data in the form of a 1000-element array.

My question is, what would be the best database structure for this type of data ?

For starters, I went with an SQL database given that that's what I'm familiar with but also because I would need my database to be well structured in order to extract/filter/analyze my data easily afterwards. However, I'm not sure how to deal with the array data! I'm thinking of creating two different tables :

- A main table with scalar parameters (with a primary key column).
- A second table containing 1000 columns, one column per array element, +1 column to use as a foreign key referring to primary key of main table.

I'm not sure, however, if this is a good solution or not, and if there are any other better solutions.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan sounds creative but the second point about having a table with a thousand columns gives me the chills to be honest.

I would say instead of having a table with a thousand columns, create a table and put each of the thousand values in there and create a relation with that table to the table containing sensors, so you know which value belongs to which sensor.

So what columns you need to create for that table for sure is:

- sensor_id, to indicate which value belongs to which sensor. Use table relation for this to make it easier.
- value, ofcourse the value from the thousand array.

I think this may make it easier to read the values if you want the values from a specific sensor.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean exactly when you say: "create a table and put each of the thousand values in there".

Comment: If you create a table. Each row contains one single value of the array consisting of thousand values. That is what I mean. @GuidoG has made a visual table for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the idea from @Yirnick 's answer

Your design would look something like this

table `Sensor`

| SensorID | SerialNumber | FirmWare |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | ABC |
| 2 | 456 | ABC |

and table `SensorData`

| SensorDataID | SensorID | Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Pressure | 12.5 |
| 2 | 1 | Temperature | 28 |
| 3 | 2 | Pressure | 11.9 |
| 4 | 2 | Temperature | 27.6 |

and so on...

now you will have thousand rows in table sensordate for each row in table sensor

The drawback of this is that the datatype if the column `Value` can not be the exact datatype for each parameter, you will have to choose a datatype that can hold every kind of value that can appear in the sensors data

But the advantage is that this is much more easy to maintain, when a new parameter is needed for your sensor data, in this design you don't need to change anything, when you have a table with thousands of columns, you need to alter that table everytime

Comment: In my case, each sensor measures a single quantity, say temperature, and generates a 1000 measurement. According to your solution, I would have for sensor 1 in table Sensor, a 1000 rows all having value 1 for column SensorID in table SensorData. Is that right?
If so, why doing this is better than creating 1000 columns per row.

Comment: so your sensor generates 1000 temperatures for each sensor, but 1000 per second ? per minute ? per day ? what if only 50 are generated ? what if 2000 are generated ? In this design that would  be no problem. In this case I would consider adding a time in the SensorData table, so you can know of each row when it was taken

Comment: Okay. I get your point. However, in my case, it's almost a certainty that I will always have 1000 points every time (the system works that way and it will not change soon). Also, except knowing when the measurement started, time-related information is not that important to me. I just need to know the order of the points; whose first, whose second, etc. That's why having a 1000 column seemed appealing.

Comment: So you need some logic to know which of the 1000 columns to fill, to keep your order. In this system you don't, just keep inserting and the time column will tell you to correct order. You can also use an identity field or sequence so you have a number to show the order the points came in if you prefer, that would probably also perform a little better

Comment: We are just giving you an alternative, at the end it is you who decides how to do it. We don't have the same information on your requirements as you do. If it was me I would use this system, but since I don't know the full story of your system, how you get your data and how you must fill it on your table, I cannot decide for you. You have my point of view, there is also the answer of @roger, so you have some stuff to think about

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I just wanted to better clarify my context/need. I guess I had the intuition that designing my table with 1000 columns should be technically possible and should satisfy my requirement but I have no clue if it would be complete nonsense to create a database with such number of columns or if there were better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that this question is going to have opinion-based answers. However, there are some general guidelines which are universally applicable.

It all depends on how that data is going to be used (i.e., read). As an example, consider the following questions:

- Do you need to retrieve individual values from those arrays?
- If so, will the search go by the value, or by its ordinal position in an array? Or maybe by something else?
- From you question, it appears that those arrays contain scalar elements (a single measurement, for example). However, it might not always be the case; sometimes you might have a tuple instead of a scalar (value type, value itself, timestamp - the list can go on). Do you have only one of these array types, or do you have both?

Why it might matter: let's say your client software will only read all values for a particular record at a time (the entire 1000-item array, without any searching inside it). In this scenario, you don't need to bother with the storage structure, and can just store each array as JSON (SQL Server supports the format starting with 2016 version, although there is no separate data type for it), or maybe even `varbinary(max)`, if the data type(s) allow an easy conversion.

Now, if you need searching capabilities, you will need something similar to what @GuidoG describes in their answer.

Comment: I'm in the last situation, where I don't need to access the individual values but I need, however, to be able to extract all the values at once and have the ability to link them to the sensor (and its other parameters) that generated them. The JSON-based solution seems appealing. However, for this to work for me, I will need to have the ability to save this data on the SQL Server where I save the main table(s). Is this what you meant by "SQL Server supports the format"?

Comment: Well, data has to somehow appear in your database, right? Some external app is going to put it there, most likely. If that app can serialise values' array into JSON, your problem is solved - just create a normal table with sensors' attributes (Id, type, etc.) and a table for data batches (SensorId, timestamp, JSON data). The former is a lookup essentially, and will be fairly static; the latter will receive the main brunt of incoming data.
If the app can't produce JSON, check what it can produce, and adapt accordingly. Or, as I've said, check if `varbinary(max)` is a viable alternative.